# What does the StackMap attribute in Code attribute do in J2ME compiled classes?

Tags: java-me

What is the point of this attribute if I can even understand how the game's bytecode works without this StackMap attribute.

What happens if I remove this attribute from J2ME application, will it start later?

Please describe this attribute in detail, and why it is used by KVM!(((

P.S. StackMap, not StackMapTable.